# Accessing Certificate Programatically for SAML2

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault, x509certificate2, sustainsys-saml2

**Setup:**

I have a .Net Framework WebForms app and just setup SAML2 using [Sustainsys.Saml2](https://saml2.sustainsys.com/en/stable/) setup on Azure. I'm also using Git for version control (VC) and Azure Key Vault for App Settings and Connection Strings.

**Question:**

What are other ways I can store and access the certificate for SAML2, even if I can access it programmatically (I'm currently accessing/setting the certificate programmatically)?

I want to prevent adding certificates to our VC as well as adding it manually to the Azure directory.

I tried looking into Key Vault Certificates, but I'm unsure if I can even use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload your certificate to your `Azure App Service --> TSLSSL setting --> Private Key Certificates (.pfx)`.

Once uploaded there you can retrieve it programmatically via `C#` with the following:

```
public static X509Certificate2 GetX509Certificate2(string certThumbprint, bool validOnly = true, StoreName storeName = StoreName.My, StoreLocation storeLocation = StoreLocation.CurrentUser) {
    using (var certStore = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation)) {
        var certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certThumbprint, validOnly);
        // Get the first cert with the thumbprint
        var cert = (X509Certificate2) certCollection.OfType<X509Certificate>().FirstOrDefault();
        certStore.Close();
        return cert;
    }
}
```

Call it via:

```
var cert = GetX509Certificate2(certificateThumbprint, false, storeLocation: StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
```

Personally, so it can work locally, deployed and on any of our devs computers, I use the following code so that it can search different locations where it may be stored:

```
var cert = GetX509Certificate2(certificateThumbprint, false, storeLocation: StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

if (cert == null) {
    cert = GetX509Certificate2(certificateThumbprint, false, storeLocation: StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
}
```